# Android 8.1 receives garbage symbols via bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I use android APP to connect to the `bluetooth` module.
But instead receiving just one symbol, it receives some garbage symbols and also few times the symbol I sent from the `bluetooth` module.
The thing is that it doesn't happen on other Androids, only on the `Android 8.1`.

[As you can see, I send '0' symbol from bluetooth module to the Android, but it also receives some garbage symbols like @@@ and again symbol '0', however I sent it only 1 time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocS7N.png)

Comment: `^@` = byte 0, as `^A` stands for Ctrl-A = byte 1. Typical for serial transmission. _Show some code_

Comment: @JoopEggen it's kinda big class for BLE Serial, do you want to see the receive function? Basically, I use BLE GATT library to receive the data, then check the first symbol, if it's the symbol I need - I perform some code. It works fine for plenty of Androids I tested except Android 8.1

Comment: Unfortunately my work does not allow me to dive into that, and I am not that good. Maybe Android forums know more.